# How Can I run react-native app in my mobile because avd is too slow

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile

Please help me. My React Native app is not running in my mobile. It works fine on the android simulator, but the performance is quiet bad.

The error is:

```
$ react-native run-android
  info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" 
  flag.
  Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 2 workers...
  info Starting JS server...
  info Installing the app...

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
  log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 8s

  error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: 
  https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
  Error: Com

  mand failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Comment: could you provide some informations about your development enviroment? and did you "enable" the developer settings on the android device?

Comment: yes i've done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because lower version of Jdk. Please update JDK version supported by Android Studio

For Reff : [Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000729/android-studio-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-runtime-invokerhel)

Comment: Thanx bro but Jdk is fine with latest version

Comment: May be because of the gradle version. you can go to the [ gradle / wrapper / gradle-wrapper.properties ] and change distributionUrl like [ distributionUrl = https \: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip ]

Comment: where is gradle installed in my pc

Comment: In Android project [ android > gradle / wrapper / gradle-wrapper.properties ]

Answer (score 0):

Try [React Native environment](http://%20https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)  to upgrade your environment because there is a thread in here [Grovy Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386847/how-can-my-gradle-build-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-classgen-verifier)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple , just connect your mobile with Android studio and on the developing mode , then select the device from Android studio and run the project the app will simply open on your phone , unless you don't have any errors in enviornment.